Determine all integers $n$ such that $n^2−4n$ is a prime number.
Got the answer $n=5$ and $n=-1$
Turned out $-1$ was incorrect according to a teacher, how could this be?

I think you are right that $n = -1$ satisfies the conditions. But you are getting close votes (not from me) because you haven't said enough about your work on the problem. If you edit your question to explain why you believe your answer to be correct, then there will be no reason to close your question and you might get some help here.

I agree that the correct answer includes $n=-1$.

We cannot possibly know what the teacher thought. But they are clearly wrong. The question is hard to answer as it is currently written, since it is not clear what lead them to believe that $-1$ is not valid.

Welcome to Math SE. Have you tried asking, or plan to try asking, this teacher why they considered $-1$ to be incorrect? Note I agree with Martin's comment that they are incorrect, but we can't possibly know what the teacher thought when making their statement.

Maybe the teacher was wrong. Or maybe the student is misquoting what the teacher said. Anyone who has taught a math class and marked an exam knows students often have ideas that are nothing like anything the teacher ever said.

$p = n^2 - 4n= n(n - 4)$ is prime for integer $n$ iff one of $n$ or $n - 4$ is a unit integer $\pm 1$ (and the other is prime, which turns out to follow automatically in this case). That gives us four possibilities for $n$ as follows:

$n = 1$, so $p = -3$.
$n = -1$, so $p = 5$.
$n = 5$, so $p = 5$.
$n = 3$, so $p = -3$.

So, if you have quoted the question correctly the answer is, that, if you are allowing primes to be negative (as is common in ring theory) then $n$ must belong to the set $\{1, -1, 5, 3\}$. If you require primes to be positive, then $n$ must belong to the set $\{-1, 5\}$ agreeing with you but not your teacher.

@CalvinLin: the iff statement is technically true in this case because if $n$ is a unit then $n - 4$ is prime and vice versa. However, I agree that that point deserves a mention for clarity and have edited the answer accordingly.

Note $n=1$ and $n=3$ both give $n^2-4n=-3$, but AFAIK it's generally considered that prime numbers are always positive integers. As such, I consider the OP to be correct with their result that $n=5$ or $n=-1$ are the only values.

@MartinBrandenburg: this is not a PSQ. The OP has proposed an answer and stated that his or her teacher disagrees with it.

@JohnOmielan: see the section headed "Prime Elements in Rings" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number. Either way, this doesn't justify the OP's teacher excluding $-1$. I have made an edit to address your point.

@RobArthan I don't think anyone's going to argue with you about prime elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, but we're talking about prime numbers here, and even the tag says "Prime numbers are natural numbers greater than 1 not divisible by any smaller number other than 1."

Yes, I realize that negative integers can be considered "prime" in certain more general situations, but there is no indication from the OP that they are considering such things, such as the ring of integers (e.g., their only question tag is "prime-numbers"). Such a relatively simple question also indicates that they are also likely only considering primes as natural numbers.

@BrianMoehring: I have edited my answer to allow for the two possible readings. Pace the definitions in the description of MSE tags, to me, to say $-3$ is not prime is as silly as to say that $0$ is not a natural number,  but perhaps I was educated when the world was a younger and simpler place for budding algebraists than it is today.

Unfortunately, even the definition of "prime element" is a little ambiguous. I've seen some authors declare that in an integral domain $R$, the element $0$ should be considered prime, as it generates a prime ideal. This leads to the conclusion that $0$ is a prime integer. Other authors require prime elements to be nonzero by fiat.

@Joe: you can argue forever about some details. You could counter the argument that  $0$ should be considered as prime by saying that a prime element $x$ is one such that ${x}$ is a minimal generating set for a prime ideal: then $0$ doesn't cut it in any ring because the empty set generates the $0$ ideal.
